# get hidden field in C#, created by javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript that can create hidden filed in my form dynamically, also generation of the hidden fields are variable it can be 200 and 1000 also. I want those value in my C# code using loop. I have tried below code but it give me only the first value static, but I need values in loop so that I can access all the values and store in my SQL database

```
string valueOfTheHiddenField = this.Request.Form.Get("0");
```

Example this type of code needed

```
for each
{
    string HiddenFieldvalue = this.Request.Form.Get("0");
    insert into sql = value Of The HiddenField
}
```

Below is the sample code i am using

```
var form = document.forms['form1'];
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.type = "hidden";
    el.name = "myHiddenField";
    el.value = trial2;
    el.id = i;
    form.appendChild(el);
}
```

These hidden fields are generated

```
<input id="0" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Root Canal Treatment ">
<input id="1" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Cosmetic Dentistry ">
<input id="2" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Fillings ">
<input id="3" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Apicectomy ">
<input id="4" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Aesthetic Crown And Bridges ">
<input id="5" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Bleaching ">
```

Comment: Your js code will create duplicate `id` elements.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120656/how-to-use-hidden-field-values-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-3) what are you looking for?

Comment: Just give the hidden input fields a unique name like in your id attribute. Then try to loop all the keys and get the value of each key, like this:
foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
     var value = Request.Form.Get(key);
 }

Comment: no ids of all hidden field are unique how to get data by using there ids of hidden files in asp,

Comment: @gdyrrahitis  can u please explain in proper code

Answer (score 2):

As in the case of your problem, You can access the hidden field(even form field) values by their name as shown below:

```
string hdnCommaSeparatedString = Request.Form["myHiddenField"];
```

This will give you a string of comma separated values of all the hidden fields, which you can split using string.split(...) overload to get the values.

```
string[] hiddenValues = hdnCommaSeparatedString.Split(',');
```

E.g. `"Root Canal Treatment ,Cosmetic Dentistry ...." //This you can split using server side logic`

**Note** This will break if the value in hidden field contains a comma and when you try to string.split in code behind with a comma(,) you will see unexpected string breaks.

E.g.

```
 <input id="0" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Root Canal, Treatment "><!--Notice a comma after Root Canal in the value & this will yield unexpected values if you string split on code behind.-->
 <input id="1" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField" value=" Cosmetic Dentistry ">
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments following are other cases to get form field values through Request.Form

***Case1:***

Hidden field names are NOT unique as in your case:

```
string[] hiddenFieldValueList = Request.Form.GetValues("myHiddenField");
//This allows parsing of hidden/form field values having comma in them
```

***Case2:***

Hidden field names are unique, you can extract the values like following:

**HTML**

```
<input id="0" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField0" value=" Root Canal, Treatment ">
<input id="1" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField1" value=" Cosmetic Dentistry ">
<input id="2" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField2" value=" Fillings, ">
<input id="3" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField3" value=" Apicectomy ">
<input id="4" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField4" value=" Aesthetic Crown And Bridges ">
<input id="5" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField5" value=" Bleaching ">
```

**Code Behind**

```
var hiddenFieldValueList = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.StartsWith("myHidden")).Select(it => Request.Form[it]).ToList();
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: value taken by this command is in comma separated  (string hdnCommaSeparatedString = Request.Form["myHiddenField"];) is there any way that i can change the defualt comma singn to any other sign, because my values also contain comma separated values what to do in that case

Comment: That's where I provided an alternate that you need to keep hidden field names unique.

Comment: @MangoPeople Please see Case1 in my edit and I think that should help you to end.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity you should create a unique name for every hidden field because if you don't, back in the code, the request will receive only one key, the 'myHiddenField', which will hold all the values.
So, the html code should be something like:

```
<input id="0" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField0" value=" Root Canal Treatment ">
<input id="1" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField1" value=" Cosmetic Dentistry ">
<input id="2" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField2" value=" Fillings ">
<input id="3" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField3" value=" Apicectomy ">
<input id="4" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField4" value=" Aesthetic Crown And Bridges ">
<input id="5" type="hidden" name="myHiddenField5" value=" Bleaching ">
```

Just append the index at the end of every name in the JS code.

Then in the C# code behind you should handle the posted form like this:

```
var keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    string value = Request.Form.Get(key);
}
```

By accessing the AllKeys property of the posted Form you get all the different keys posted, which are the names of the respective input fields. So Keys == Names.

You have the key, so you can get the value, by using the Get method of the Request.Form property. This accepts either an index or the key (name) of the input field.

Then as soon as you've got the value you can proceed with your scenario.

Hope this helps.